# Create tar file that stores filenames, but not file contents

Tags: tar

Basically I want to create a tar image of a folder structure, but not store the actual file contents. So when I untar the file I want to get the original folders, filenames, timestamps, etc.., but all zero-length files instead of the original file contents.

The intent here is to capture the folder structure of a gigantic folder (gigabytes in size) without creating a multi-gigabyte tar file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should mention I need this on stock RHEL 6.7

Answer (score 4):

If your `cp` is [powerful enough](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation), you can do this:

```
cp -a --attributes-only olddir newdir
```

Where `newdir` does not exist (yet) and `--attributes-only` means

> Copy only the specified attributes of the source file to the destination. […]

This won't copy data; regular files in `newdir` will be of zero size. Note you need to be root to replicate all the attributes (e.g. ownership), so maybe you need `sudo cp …`. Instead of `-a` you can use more specific options to only replicate the attributes you really need.

Anyway, after you create `newdir` containing empty files, simply `tar` this directory instead of `olddir`.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea but it seems my cp doesn't support --attributes-only :(

Answer (score 4):

`star` supports this since 18 years.... try:

```
star -c -dump -meta ... | star -tv
```

This lists all entries as 'm'eta type files...

```
star -c -dump -meta ... | star -C todir -xmeta
```

extracts all files a 0 byte sized files.

```
star -c -dump -meta ... | star -C todir -xmeta -force-hole
```

extracts all files as files of the original size with no data (sparse file).

`star` is part of the schilytools.

Comment: Thanks, but running external tools is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Mmm `gtar` is an external tool as well. `star` is what I use since 38 years without problems. BTW: star is on SUSE since it is used to implement `pax` via a symlink to `star`.