# How can I clone an entire remote directory tree and file structure but have empty files, via the command line?

Tags: command-line, rsync, scp, file-copy

On a remote production server I have a directory that has more than 15 Terabytes of data. Also, in addition to Linux permission, ACLs are heavily used to allow departments, users, and daemons fine tuned access.

For our CI/CD pipeline and automated testing, I need to test how changes to these permissions affect the system, but before I can do that, I need a clone of what's on production in the test environment.

I obviously can't clone 15 Terabyte of data, and I really don't care about the data, I just care about the meta data (filenames, permissions, timestamps - basically all the info `ls -lah` returns.)

It's easy to see what I'm trying to do with how I'm using `rsync`:

```
rsync -aAr --include='*/' --exclude='*' remoteuser@remoteproduction.com:/my/directory/ /test/directory/
```

This gives me exactly what I need from a directory standpoint. If `rsync` had an option to allow files to be copied over with 0 content but filenames and attributes intact, problem solved. (Does it?)

For now, after I run the above rsync command for the directories, here is how I'm approaching this.

```
ssh remoteuser@remoteproduction.com 'find /my/directory -type f -exec ls -lah {} \;' > my.production.directory.files.txt
```

This gives me a local file where the contents contain lines of data like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 owner  group    15K Oct 13 10:07 /my/directory/jobs.txt
```

That has 9 fields, and I'm passing it to awk and bash:

```
cat my.production.directory.files.txt | awk '{print "touch " $9 " && chown "$3":"$4" "$9}' | bash
```

I feel like there has to be a better way. before I filter that file through other commands to apply `chmod` and the original timestamps, isn't there a more efficient way to do this? Something like `cp` has with `--attributes-only` like `touch` and `chown` can do with --reference, except against a remote file system?

Note, the answer must be executed directly on the command line. I cannot upload or rely on any scripts. Also, I know getfacl -R and setfacl will restore the permissions, but it does not restore timestamp and non-permissions related file data (that I'm aware.)

Comment: Can you `cp --attributes-only` *within* the remote system and then download *the copy* to the local?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create tar file that stores filenames, but not file contents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604384/create-tar-file-that-stores-filenames-but-not-file-contents)

Comment: ah, both of these are creative approaches. The only folder I'd possibly have write access to is /tmp. The only gotcha I can think of is if / when the production image is fully immutable. I don't have star on the system in question and can't install it, but I like the idea of forcing all this to happen on the remote machine and just dl'ing the compressed structure. I'll test and update.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crazy idea: what if you use [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs)?

1. Mount the remote directory locally using `sshfs`:

   ```
   sshfs remoteuser@remotehost:/my/directory /mountpoint
   ```
2. Use the `--attributes-only` option to `cp` to recreate the file structure:

   ```
   cp -a --attributes-only /mountpoint /test/directory
   ```
3. Unmount the sshfs filesystem:

   ```
   fusermount -u /mountpoint
   ```

This doesn't require installing any additional software on the remote host.

Comment: I like this a lot. Currently the images that are used in testing duplicate the prod infrastructure where sshfs isn't installed. But I'll see if I can alter the devops job to include it. On a related note, I often pipe or redirect remote stdout data to local (ssh remote@host "my command outout" > localfile), and I'm wondering if `cp` can be used similarly, especially if I use the <(command) convention which gives stdout its own device file descriptor as if it's manipulating on-disk files. Thanks for the creative thinking, and let me know if you have ideas in those directions too.